# Issue with pandas.setindex() to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetimeindex

I have a pandas dateframe with stock market data. There is a date column ('date').

When trying to access a date using a string, I receive:

```
KeyError: 'the label [1981-02-17 00:00:00] is not in the [index]'
```

I explicitly set the index to be a datetime index by calling

```
self.data['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(self.data['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
self.data.set_index(pandas.DatetimeIndex(self.data['date'], inplace=True))
```

Here's my class:

```
class ohlcData:
    def __init__(self, ticker=None, csv=None, intrinio=False):
        if ticker is not None:
            self.ticker = ticker.upper()
        else:
            self.ticker = None

        if csv is not None:
            name_len = csv.find(".csv")
            if name_len is -1:
                raise ValueError("CSV file should be named ticker.csv where ticker is the stock ticker.")
            else:
                self.ticker = csv[0:name_len].upper()
                self.data = pandas.read_csv(csv)

                self.data['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(self.data['date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
                self.data.set_index(self.data['date'], inplace=True)

        if not intrinio:
            self.data = pandas.DataFrame()
        else:
            self.read_from_intrinio()
```

Relevant excerpt of main:

```
aapl = ohlcData(csv="aapl.csv")
print(aapl.data.loc[datetime.date(1981, 2,17)])
```

Resulting in:

```
KeyError: 'the label [1981-02-17] is not in the [index]'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, `self.data.set_index('date')` should be enough. Also, how are you *actually* trying to access it? maybe the time at the end makes a difference depending on your data

Comment: df[‘1981-02-17’]

Comment: What happens if `df.set_index("date").loc[datetime.date(1981, 2,17)]` ?

Comment: Because it seems you have a typo in your second line. `inplace=True` should be inside `set_index` and not `DateTimeIndex()`. So, if the above works, then thats the reason.. i.e. 
`self.data.set_index(pandas.DatetimeIndex(self.data['date']), inplace=True)` would do

Comment: when trying `df.set_index("date").loc[datetime.date(1981, 2,17)]` I get `KeyError: 'the label [1981-02-17] is not in the [index]`

Comment: I also fixed the typo I had and still receive an error :(

Comment: Ok, post your whole code related to `self.data` so we can have a better idea of what is the situation

Comment: I updated my original post